# How to expose the business logic as a RESTful web service to be consumed by a mobile application?

Tags: java, json, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am working on the server side of a mobile application. One of the requirements I have is to implement the server using Java EE, JPA, EJB, and JSON.

I am new to Java EE but I did some reading and so far managed to build the business logic by implementing the Pojos and the EJBs of the project.

Where I am encountering difficulties is in figuring out how to expose my EJBs as a RESTful web service that can be consumed by the client side of the application. I could find some documentation and tutorials but all of it was related to building a backend for a website as opposed to mobile.

What are the best practices in exposing the business logic as a RESTful web service to a mobile application in a Java EE environment?

Comment: Alright, thank you for letting me know. I have removed that part from my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your app server is but with JavaEE 6 and 7, you can do this fairly easily.  Take a look at [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsonp005.htm) for a good starting point.  In general, a simple service would look something like:

```
@Path("/login")
public class LoginService  {    

    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @POST
    public Response login(LoginRequest loginRequest) throws Exception {  
    // your code
    }
```

where LoginRequest in this case is simple Java POJO that has an equivalent in the JavaScript world.

Note that it doesn't matter what the client side is - the server just wants the JSON encoded object to come in and it can be a browser or a native mobile app.

A bit of an issue is how to initialize your app servers underlying Rest framework.  Some use web.xml, some use a specially annotated class.  That is a bit of a different question - let us know which app server you're using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I started seeing what needs to be done. For the server I am using glassfish 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this sample https://github.com/AdamBien/airhacks/tree/master/javaee-sample .

This class is all that you need to bootstrap your rest application: https://github.com/AdamBien/airhacks/blob/master/javaee-sample/src/main/java/com/airhacks/JAXRSConfiguration.java

and this one expose a rest resource using a stateless EJB:
https://github.com/AdamBien/airhacks/blob/master/javaee-sample/src/main/java/com/airhacks/messaging/boundary/MessagesResource.java